# How to use functions from a module in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to use the functions that come with the List and String modules in OCaml.

How can I import them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard modules are available just by naming them. You can use the functions by prefixing with the module name:

```
# List.length [1;2;3;4;5];;
- : int = 5
# String.length "12345";;
- : int = 5
```

There are quite a few other ways to handle the naming, but this is the basic one that you should start with.